# Does the parseInt() method delete all zero's?

Tags: java, android, parseint

I'm using this code to set the id of any button:

```
String s = "" + i + j;
int getal = Integer.parseInt(s);
button.setId(getal);
```

Variables "i" and "j" are always from 0 tot 9. A single digit. However, if "i" is 0 then the parseInt() method deletes it, I think.

For example: when i=0 and j=6 the outcome of variable "getal" wil be 6 and not 06. I need it to be 06. Does somebody maybe know an other way of converting strings to ints?

Comment: If it's an int, `06` or `00000006` or `6` are the same thing (unless you mean octal, in which case your input doesn't work - octal is limited to `0-7`).

Comment: I think it would help for us to know why it needs to be 06? What are you doing to the ID later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Integer can't be "06" - it is either 6 or it is a String.

So, the `setId` will not see any difference between "06" and "6".

If you really need the leading Zero, you could either save it as a `String` or as an `int[]`

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be using just s represent the value that you need? Integers store just numbers and 06 and 6 are the same numbers so when you store it in integer, you will get 6 and not 06.

Answer (score 1):

Leading zeros are not a property of the **value** of the number, they're a property of its **representation** as a string.

`Integer.parseInt()` **parses** a string to determine the corresponding integer value. Once you have extracted the value, the formatting is by necessity lost.

What you want is not another way of converting strings to ints, but another way of converting ints to strings, to **display** the value to the user with your desired formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Integers are a datatype for storing whole numbers. The datatype itself is not responsible for it's representation (i.e. 6, 06, 0x06, 00000110 would all be valid potential formats for the number six).

If you need a specific format then you'll need to store it in a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can *not* get the exact value `06` with an `int` type as that is defined as just the value `6`. Hence you must use a `String` or similar structure to model the value `06`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Johan has said ints can not contains a leading zero. If you wanted to stick with using integers you could format the output

```
int getal = Integer.parseInt(s);
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("00");
button.setId(formatter.format(getal));
```